# Refreshing image at constant frame rate using Observable.Interval is slower than it should

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

Update:

I isolated the problem to its core components and a much shorter minimal working example in another question:

[Observable.Interval not updating UI with expected frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511743/observable-interval-not-updating-ui-with-expected-frequency)

---

I need to display a sequence of images (which are read from a folder) as a "movie", at a constant, previously known, frame-rate.

I have an Image control in WPF, whose Source is data-bound to a ViewModel property `Image`. I then proceed to update that image on a timely basis, using an `Observable.Interval` event source. For each elapsed interval, the `UpdateImage` is called, which updates the image inside a `Task.Run()` call.

My problem is: when I experimentally increase effective frame-rate (which depends on actual frame-rate and also on playback speed), the playback keeps being at normal speed up tu a given value. Above that value, it starts to look slower.

I believe that it has to do with `RaisePropertyChanged` call, but I'm not sure. I tried using `SubscribeOnDispatcher` (or whas it `ObserveOnDispatcher`?) but anyway it didnt have an effect.

Questions are:
 - What I am doing wrong?
 - How could I investigate and resolve the problem?

UPDATE:
It's worth mentioning that the getter for `Image` calls `CreateImageForIndex()`, which is a method that could have a non-trivial cost. Would it be possible to "async" it?

ViewModel (partial):

```
    CancellationTokenSource _cancelPlay;
    double _speed;

    public void Play(double speed)
    {
        _speed = speed;

        _cancelPlay = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0 / (Math.Abs(speed) * Exame.Model.Configurações.FrameRate)))
                  .Subscribe(t => ExecuteRun(), _cancelPlay.Token);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _cancelPlay?.Cancel();
    }



    void ExecuteRun()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Index = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(_model.MaxIndex, Index + 1 * Math.Sign(_speed)));
        });
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get { return _model.Index; }
        set
        {
            _model.Index = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(null); // this tells view to get a new value for `Image` too!
        }
    }

    public ImageSource Image => _model.CreateImageForIndex(Index);
```

Comment: Have you considered looking at TimeSpan.FromSeconds? Note that value passed on it will only be considered accurate to the nearest millisecond. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PaoloGo Ouch! Gonna look at that right now, since this is a _very_ likely cause to my problem. Thanks for now, I'll keep you informed.

Comment: @PaoloGo I changed `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` to `TimeSpan.FromTicks`, converting my seconds to ticks properly, but unfortunately the problem continues. It's a slowing-down in the order of 20% (an image sequence 5 seconds long is taking 7 seconds to playback, from beginning to end).

Comment: Consider passing the specific propertyName on your RaisePropertyChanged. Passing null to it will notify view that ALL properties have changed. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @PaoloGo Well, that's actually what happens: I have a viewmodel with one settable property (`Index`) and other three that are readonly, where _every_ of those tree are calculated from the value of `Index`. So instead of writing four named `RaisePropertyChanged` calls, I used only one, anonymous (null) one.

Comment: Could you add more code? it's really difficult to get the whole picture of what your program does based on what is currently posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159617/discussion-between-paolo-go-and-heltonbiker).

Comment: Well constructing image is costly and takes some time, so you cannot expect your code to be able to do this at arbitrary frame rate.

Comment: `the playback keeps being at normal speed up tu a given value. Above that value, it starts to look slower.` Can you update your post to reflect what that value is?

Comment: I isolated the problem in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47511743/observable-interval-not-updating-ui-with-expected-frequency

Answer (score 0):

I've followed a hint from @Enigmativity (in the other answer I posted), that in Windows the resolution of timers is 15ms at most.

So I tested another strategy: spinning a while loop with an "when elapsed" condition, similar to a game loop, measuring time with a `Stopwatch`, and everything is working fine now.

```
    public void Play(double speed)
    {
        _speed = speed;

        _cancelPlay?.Cancel();
        _cancelPlay = new CancellationTokenSource();

        Task.Run(() => PlayLoop(_cancelPlay.Token), _cancelPlay.Token);
    }

    void PlayLoop(CancellationToken token)
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        double previous = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        double timeInterval = 1000.0 / (Math.Abs(_speed) * _exame.Model.Configurações.FrameRate);

        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var current = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            var elapsed = current - previous;
            if (elapsed > timeInterval)
            {
                Índice = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(ÍndiceMáximo, Índice + 1 * Math.Sign(_speed)));
                previous = current;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've put an answer on your previous question.