# Observable.Interval not updating UI with expected frequency

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, system.reactive

I am trying to simulate the behavior of a clock. For that, I create an `Observable.Interval` that, after a specified time interval, updates the value of a property by the equivalent amount of time. The value is data-bound to the GUI.

The problem is: the "clock" runs quite slower than expected, that is, it takes longer than one second for the clock value to increase one second.

The finer the desired time resolution (the value of `MILLIS_INTERVAL` below), the worse the problem gets (I tested it with values of 1, 10, 100 and other submultiples of 1000, since `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds` is documented to have a maximum resolution of 1ms).

I would expect the observable callback to run asynchronously, and be fired at regular intervals, possibly in parallel, despite the time it takes to execute, but it seems that the larger the frequency, the more it lags.

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

namespace IntervalClock
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public double TimeSeconds
        {
            get { return _timeSeconds; }
            set
            {
                _timeSeconds = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TimeSeconds"));
            }
        }
        double _timeSeconds;


        const double MILLIS_INTERVAL = 10;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MILLIS_INTERVAL))
                      .Subscribe(token => TimeSeconds += MILLIS_INTERVAL / 1000);
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="IntervalClock.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:IntervalClock"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeSeconds, StringFormat=N3}" FontSize="30"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: @mm8 and how could I solve this?

Comment: You mean getting the callbacks to run in parallel, independant of each other?

Comment: Windows isn't a real-time operating system so the timers aren't perfect. You can have significant drift. Also the smallest resolution on Windows is 15.6 ms - so anything less than this is effectively 15.6 ms no matter what you do.

Comment: @mm8 yeah. I just tried to put the callback inside a `Task.Run()` but to no avail.

Comment: @mm8 - The timer **does not** call `OnNext` on the same thread.

Answer (score 2):

The `Observable.Interval` operator times the interval between running each `.OnNext` to fire. So if the `.OnNext` take 0.1s and your interval is 1.0s then you have an effective period of 1.1s. But of course Windows isn't a real-time operating system so it has drift. Your actual time can vary even more - especially when your system is under load.

Here's how I would do this:

```
var interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0);
Observable
    .Create<long>(o =>
    {
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        return
            Observable
                .Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(interval.TotalSeconds / 10.0))
                .Select(x => (long)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds)
                .DistinctUntilChanged()
                .Subscribe(o);
    })
```

The use of the `StopWatch` gives you excellent accuracy for the time elapsed. The timer fires roughly 10x more often than the `interval` so that it has a +/- 10% error on when it fires, but the result is the same - you have a very accurate "seconds" value returned from this observable, just not return precisely on every second.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I may have given the impression that I want to make a sort of clock, but what I actually want is to "clock" the playback of image sequences, which are taken from a camera at a known frame-rate. So, for a frame-rate of 30, the problem formulation would be "I need an observable that would fire a callback asynchronously at each 1/30th of a second". Your solution would eliminate the problem of accumulated drift, which was my main problem, but it seems to me that the frame-to-frame would jitter a bit and perhaps skip some frames.

Comment: Another possibility, and a very good one (although possibly violating MVVM a little bit), is to subscribe to the `CompositionTarget.Rendering` event in the View (the actual UserControl displaying the image sequence), so that the clock signals would come from the very rendering engine. Then it could get the elapsed time from Stopwatch, and calculate the corresponding frame index to display.

Answer (score 1):

The timer seems to call `OnNext` on the same thread so the callback isn't being executed "asynchronously".

You could create your own method that invokes the callback on a thread pool thread. Here is a basic example using the `System.Timers.Timer` class:

```
public static IObservable<long> Interval(TimeSpan interval)
{
    return Observable.Create<long>(observer =>
    {
        long i = 0;
        Timer _timer = new Timer(interval.TotalMilliseconds);
        _timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => observer.OnNext(i++);
        _timer.Start();

        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            _timer.Stop();
            _timer.Dispose();
        });
    });
}
```

Usage (just call your own `Interval` method instead of `Observable.Interval`):

```
Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MILLIS_INTERVAL))
                  .Subscribe(token => TimeSeconds += MILLIS_INTERVAL / 1000);
```

This should make the "callback run asynchronously, and be fired at regular intervals, possibly in parallel, despite the time it takes to execute, ...".

Comment: Since it wasn't me, I'll need to ask: why the downvote?

Comment: @heltonbiker - The `Observable.Interval` **does not** call `OnNext` on the same thread. The first sentence is just wrong. Also, there's an Rx operator that already does what mm8 has proposed - `Observable.Timer(interval)`. There's no need to create this code. This code will also **not** make it fire at regular intervals - all timers in Windows drift.

Comment: @heltonbiker - The operator is `Observable.Timer(interval, interval)`. You have to repeat the interval otherwise the timer doesn't repeat.